# Fill blanks with adjacent fields with conditions

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I want to fill(row-wise) blanks with "adjacent fields text" if the same or "X". Kindly suggest (`AWK`/`sed`) solution. (Additional requirement: Distance of empty fields matters while computing i.e using the header record, blank fields distance should be < 100). Otherwise fill with  "X" even if adjacent fields matched.

```
Example of blank fields filled with "X" even after matching: Line0 $612-$822.
```

Input(tab-separated)

```
ID  577 592 598 600 612 650 700 822 825 830 840 870
Line0   A           A                   A           A
Line1   B           B                   NA          B
Line2   B           A                   A           A
```

Explanation of exceptional empty fields

```
Exceptional intervals are Columns ID-600 to ID-822 because the distance is greater than 100
```

Expected output

```
ID  577 592 598 600 612 650 700 822 825 830 840 870
Line0   A   A   A   A   X   X   X   X   A   A   A   A
Line1   B   B   B   B   X   X   X   X   NA  X   X   B
Line2   B   X   X   A   X   X   X   X   A   A   A   A
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. To help contributors understand your problem, pleas add some more information on your input and desired output. Is your input file tab-separated (or is a combination of tabs, spaces etc. possible)? Is the lower example the result of what you have tried, or an example what the output should look like?

Comment: @AdminBee, guided. Basically, if Adjacent fields in a row are the same, fill empty fields with Adjacent value i.e A---A will be AAAAA., thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understood your request correctly, but how about

```
awk -F"\t" '
NR > 1  {i = 2
         while (i<=NF)  {if (!$i)       {while (!$(++i)) ;
                                         for (j=LAST+1; j<i; j++) $j = ($LAST == $i)?$LAST:"X"
                                        }
                         LAST = i++
                        }
        }
1
' OFS="\t" file

ID      s577    s592    s598    s600    s612    s650    s700    s822    s825    s830    s840    s870
line0   A       A       A       A       A       A       A       A       A       A       A       A
line1   B       B       B       B       X       X       X       X       NA      X       X       B
line2   B       X       X       A       A       A       A       A       A       A       A       A
```

Annotated version on request:

```
awk -F"\t" '
NR > 1  {i = 2                                                  # Don't work on the header line
         while (i<=NF)  {if (!$i)       {while (!$(++i)) ;      # check every field if empty and
                                                                # increment i while seeing empty
                                                                # fields; i now holds next non-
                                                                # empty field 
                                         for (j=LAST+1; j<i; j++) $j = ($LAST == $i)?$LAST:"X"
                                                                # fill the empty fields with "X"
                                                                # or last non-empty field's value
                                                                # depending on actual and last
                                                                # fields' values being equal or not
                                        }
                         LAST = i++                             # retain last non-empty field
                        }
        }
1                                                               # default action: print
' OFS="\t" file
```

Comment: you nailed it. Please provide some explanations about the script! I just had to add a dummy column at the end of the file so that the last blank can be computed correctly.

Comment: Is there a "last blank"? Not obious from your sample... And, if there were - should it become "X" or the last non-empty field's value?

Comment: @glen-viet: added comments for explanation.

Comment: Succinct explanations, many thanks @RudiC. I hope I can use it to handle important conditions I forgot to put in the question, i.e Distance of blanks matters if more than 100 replace with X even if adjacent matched (header modified to integers). "Last blank" is not an issue, I suppose input problem on my end, not the script.

Comment: Really sorry to bother you again! Please correct the follow-up script trying to account for distance between headers.awk -F"\t" '
NR>0  {i = 2
         while (i<=NF)  {if (!$i)       {while (!$(++i)&&((i-LAST)<100)) ;
                                         for (j=LAST+1; j<i; j++) $j = ($LAST == $i)?$LAST:"X"
                                        }
                         LAST = i++
                        }
        }
1
' OFS="\t" INPUTAWK.txt > inputAWKFilled.txt

Comment: Try (untested) to adapt the "conditional assignment": $j = (($LAST == $i) && ((LAST-i) < 100))?$LAST:"X"

Comment: Not successful, I suppose another variable is required to track the headers but I have no idea how to introduce!

Comment: Add an (abbreviated) example.

Comment: edited the original post and added an example of expected output. I hope it's ok! .Thank you.

Comment: Make it `(i-LAST)` in lieu of `(LAST-i)`.

Comment: No change! This is the script am using `awk -F"\t" '
NR > 0  {i = 2
         while (i<=NF)  {if (!$i)       {while (!$(++i)) ;
                                         for (j=LAST+1; j<i; j++) $j = (($LAST == $i) && (((i-LAST)) < 100))?$LAST:"X"
                                        }
                         LAST = i++
                        }
        }
1
' OFS="\t" INPUTAWK.txt > inputAWKFilled.txt`

Comment: Can check header record using `head -1 INPUTAWK.txt | sed 's/* delimiter*/\n/ g' |nl > inputAWKColumns.txt` but dont know how to incorporate into the script

Comment: `NR>0` is a non-condition as it will always be true. I'm not sure what your request is, now. Please specify in detail. The `(i-LAST)` condition worked when I tested it with your sample (reduced to 10 empty columns)

Comment: I have added an image to illustrate, briefly; if the interval of empty fields is greater than 100 based on header difference;it should be filled with "X". In my sample for example, all fields in columns between ID-600 and ID-825.

Comment: Code using but not successful .Thanks again.```
awk -F"\t" '
NR > 1  {i = 2
         while (i<=NF)  {if (!$i)       {while (!$(++i)) ;
                                         for (j=LAST+1; j<i; j++) $j = (($LAST == $i) && ((i - LAST) < 100))?$LAST:"X"
                                        }
                         LAST = i++
                        }
        }
1
' OFS="\t" unix.txt > unixFilled2.txt 
```